# how to add glyphicon to spring struts menu

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, velocity, glyphicons

I am working on a spring hibernate maven project generated by appfuse.org's tutorial. There is a `menu-config.xml` file which contains all menu item and role configurations. How can i add bootstrap's glyphicon to my menu items? Here is the content of `menu-config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MenuConfig>
    <Displayers>
        <Displayer name="Velocity" type="net.sf.navigator.displayer.VelocityMenuDisplayer"/>
    </Displayers>
<Menus>
    <Menu name="Home" title="home.title" page="/home/" roles="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
    <Menu name="Search" title="search.title" page="/search"
          roles="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER,ROLE_ANONYMOUS,IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <Menu name="UserMenu" title="menu.user" description="User Menu" page="/userform" roles="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
    <Menu name="AdminMenu" title="menu.admin" description="Admin Menu" roles="ROLE_ADMIN" page="/admin/users">
        <Item name="ViewUsers" title="menu.admin.users" page="/admin/users"/>
        <Item name="ActiveUsers" title="home.activeUsers" page="/admin/activeUsers"/>
        <Item name="ReloadContext" title="menu.admin.reload" page="/admin/reload"/>
        <Item name="FileUpload" title="menu.selectFile" page="/fileupload"/>
    </Menu>
    <Menu name="Logout" title="user.logout" page="/logout" roles="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
</Menus>
</MenuConfig>
```

I could not find a solution needed for me.

Comment: You need to find templates files for your menu and modify them.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but where are the template files located?

Comment: @khansan  I am  facing a problem i think u can answer to this question please check to this question wat i have asked but didnt find solution   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28602419/spring-menu-configuration  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally figured it out: there a re some template files in appfuse maven spring mvc project with extension of `.vm`. In order to add a glyphicon one has to open `navbarMenu.vm` file and add

```
<span class="caret"></span>
```

in the body of needed `<li>` tag.