# Spring Menu Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am working with the spring MVC 4 and configuring the menu in my home page which is to be shown based on role which i have define. So in my menu-config.xml i am defining as

```
<Menu name="Company" title="menu.companyTitle" page="/xxx/yyy/zzzz">
   <Item name="NewCompanyRequest" roles="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER" title="menu.NewCompanyRequest" page="/admin/companyRequestList" />
   <Item name="editCompanies" roles="ROLE_ADMIN" title="menu.editCompanies" page="/xx/yyy/ccc" />
</menu>
<Menu name="Exchaged" title="menu.admin.aboutCompany" page="/exchaged" roles="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
```

Means the above item name **editCompanies** should be visible to ADMIN user only and it is working fine but in UI it disturbed the next menu **Exchaged** and bring in one.

I have tried to number of steps but din't work and not found solution.

Comment: What markup language is that?

Comment: You have to incorrect omit tag for `<Menu>`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, You are using wrong closing tag for Your `<Menu>` tag. I have corrected it and You can see it below code.

Next, You cannot add `roles` attribute in `<Item>` tag. You have to give this attribute in `<Menu>` tag instead. So, Your menu should be like below:

```
<Menu name="Company" title="menu.companyTitle" page="#" roles="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER">
    <Item name="NewCompanyRequest"  title="menu.NewCompanyRequest" page="/admin/companyRequestList" />
    <Item name="editCompanies" title="menu.editCompanies" page="/xx/yyy/ccc" />
</Menu> ...
```

or like below:

```
<Menu name="Company" title="menu.companyTitle" page="/xxx/yyy/zzzz" roles="ROLE_ADMIN">
    <Item name="NewCompanyRequest"  title="menu.NewCompanyRequest" page="/admin/companyRequestList" />
    <Item name="editCompanies" title="menu.editCompanies" page="/xx/yyy/ccc" />
</Menu> ...
```

or You can make dropdown menus separate menu and give separate role permission like below:

```
<Menu name="NewCompanyRequest" roles="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER" title="menu.NewCompanyRequest" page="/admin/companyRequestList" />
<Menu name="editCompanies" roles="ROLE_ADMIN" title="menu.editCompanies" page="/xx/yyy/ccc" />
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Wat if i want two item to be in one menu its requirement though i knw that separated menu solve the problem but i want in one. So that among the two item each will be shown respective to the role assign.

Comment: Is it working as You expected? I mean, `<Menu>` with two `<Item>`s, each with different role permission?  If Yes, what is the problem?